# How to Read Data Compare of two table

Tags: android, sql

I Have Two Tables , Table1 Contains 10 Users Regular Data, Table2 Contains 3 vip users username(same as table1) only . Now how can I Get All 7 Non-VIP Users data using sql? Platform IS sqlite Database Android

Comment: Please provide your current code and describe what is the issue with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somnath,
It would be great if you would provide the database platform and actual table schemas in your question. Not having this information requires people to make assumptions. Anyway, I think it would like like this.

```
select *
from table1
where not exists(select * from table2 where table2.username = table1.username)
```

Comment: Opp sorry , I forgot That Now I Have Updated The Platform

Comment: actualy its showing the 3 vip member name 1 want the 7 non-vip member name

Comment: Fixed the query.  Guess I was 1/2 a sleep when posted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
SELECT * from Table1
WHERE user_id
NOT IN (SELECT user_id from Table2);
```

Translating to: Select everything in Table 1 where user_id doesn't exist in list of user_id's from Table2.